# Debug failure in Typescript when converting React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to convert an existing extensive React project to TypeScript.

I have `webpack` 2.7.0, `ts-loader` 3.5.0, `typescript` 2.9.2, `source-map-loader` 0.2.3, and the type declaration files for `react` and `react-dom`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/", // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": true, // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true, // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "es6", // specify module code generation
        "jsx": "react", // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
        "target": "es5", // specify which target of JavaScript should be emitted from the given TypeScript
        "allowJs": true // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/"
    ]
}
```

Here is a bit of my `webpack.config.js`

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
    ...other stuff for css-loader and url-loader
```

When I run `npm start`, I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)
    at getFirstJSDocTag (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)
    at Object.getJSDocType (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13173:19)
    at getContextualSignature (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41002:32)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44621:43)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45681:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)
    at getWidenedTypeFromJSSpecialPropertyDeclarations (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30757:46)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31032:28)
    at getTypeOfSymbol (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31242:24)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42338:53)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpression (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42293:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45663:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Path\to\nodemodules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/app/index.js
```

This build worked before starting my TypeScript migration but now it is not. I don't have any `ts` or `tsx` files yet. Everything is just `js`/`jsx`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm was having exactly the same issue just now, and couldn't find any docs to help me. It looks like a Typescript bug in 2.9.

Try upgrading typescript@next (which as of today is 3.0.0-dev.20180703). That got me over the line!